# split field into array in awk, then search each term in another file

Tags: arrays, awk, split, gawk

I'm trying to de-compose a field from a specific file into an array, and then check if each term appears in a second file (which has been already stored in another array). The goal is to merge information from both files.

The first `file1` (the one with the field I want to split) looks like that:

```
data1=data2=data3 some more stuff
data4=data1 this are things
data2=data5 more text here
...
```

While `file2` has this structure:

```
data1 10
data2 20
data3 35
data4 15
data5 60
```

I want to split the the first field of `file1` using `=`, then search each of the splitted terms in the second file, and print everything in the following format:

`output`:

```
data1=data2=data3 some more stuff 10
data1=data2=data3 some more stuff 20
data1=data2=data3 some more stuff 35
data4=data1 this are things 15
data4=data1 this are things 10
data2=data5 more text here 20
data2=data5 more text here 60
```

So far, I've got this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {
l[$1] = $2; next
} {
la=split($1,a,"=")
for(x=1;x<=la;x++)
  print $0,l[a[$x]]
}' file2 file1 > output
```

First (when `NR==FNR`), I store `file2` data in the array `l` using the first field as key.

Then I parse the next file in the following manner: for each record, I split the field `$1` into an array `la` using `=` as the separator. `la` variable stores the number of terms in the array `a`.

For each element in array `a` (`for` loop), I look for the corresponding key in array `l` and output the current content + `l` value.

But, for some reason, I only get the content from `file1` (current, unwanted output):

```
data1=data2=data3 some more stuff 
data1=data2=data3 some more stuff 
data1=data2=data3 some more stuff 
data4=data1 this are things 
data4=data1 this are things 
data2=data5 more text here 
data2=data5 more text here
```

Any ideas on what might be wrong with my code?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Never use the letter `l` (el) as a variable name as it looks far too much line the number `1` (one), indistinguishable in some fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. It was an issue with variable naming.

This is the correct code:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {
l[$1] = $2; next
} {
la=split($1,a,"=")
for(x=1;x<=la;x++)
  print $0,l[a[x]]
}' file2 file1 > output
```

The key is in the printing function. It now reads `print $0,l[a[x]]` instead of `print $0,l[a[$x]]`. The loop is using `x` as its internal counter, not `$x`. Changing that now points to the correct key in array `l` (from `file2`).

I'm leaving the post because it looks like this question hasn't been posed before. Please tell me if you think it's not useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

If your tokens are fixed length you can do pattern match without splitting the field

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}
              {for(k in a) if($1~k) print $0, a[k]}' file2 file1

data1=data2=data3 some more stuff 10
data1=data2=data3 some more stuff 20
data1=data2=data3 some more stuff 35
data4=data1 this are things 10
data4=data1 this are things 15
data2=data5 more text here 20
data2=data5 more text here 60
```